# paste in R in combination with other functions (e.g. transform)

Tags: r

When I use loop functions I sometimes get an error message, when I try to paste something into another function. I realized, that the problem is not the loop, but the function I'm using. I noticed this for some functions and I want to unterstand why it is not working.

For example:

> 

```
example <- data.frame(
  u = c(1,0,0),
  v = c(0,1,1)
)

example <- transform(
  example, code = ifelse(u==1,"u","v")
)
```

works fine. But if, for some reason, I want to insert something with paste, it does not work anymore:

```
example <- transform(
  example, paste0("co","de") = ifelse(u==1,"u","v")
)
```

I thought maybe the quotes are the problem, but

```
example <- transform(
  example, noquote(paste0("co","de")) = ifelse(u==1,"u","v")
)
```

does not work either.

I just want to unterstand why some functions don't work if I paste something.

Comment: Parameter names for function calls are not evaluated. `noquote` is just for printing and doesn't have anything to do with making a value a symbol rather than a string. Technically you can build parameter names using something like `do.call` with a named list in base R, but usually there are better ways to perform the transformation such as creating all the new columns and then renaming them after word. But the `transform` function really isn't the best for this case. The big difference is that some places R expects a symbol and you can't always use a string in those places.

Comment: Just adding to that, the function you are using (`paste0()`) returns a `character` vector (= string), so you can definitely use it *if and when* R expects some sort of string. E.g. `ifelse(u==1, paste0("u"), paste0("v"))` is silly but interpreted correctly by R. You can definitely use it, but only when you require a `character` type.

Answer (score 0):

The name of an argument must be a fixed string, not an expression that evaluates to the name. We can get around this in a variety of ways.

The first few alternatives show how to use transform.  The next alternative uses within/assign giving a particularly compact solution.  We then show a  other base R approaches followed by performing the calculation in three different packages.  At the end we show how to use parse/eval although the use of eval is discouraged so you might not want to pick that alternative.

```
example2 <- transform(example, X = ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v"))
names(example2)[names(example2) == "X"] <- paste0("co", "de")

example2 <- transform(example, X = ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v"))
names(example2) <- sub("^X$", paste0("co", "de"), names(example2))

example2 <- transform(example, X = ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v"))
names(example2)[ncol(example2)] <- paste0("co", "de")

within(example, assign(paste0("co", "de"), ifelse(u==1,"u","v")))

replace(example, paste0("co", "do"), with(example, ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v")))

cbind(example, with(example, 
  setNames(data.frame(ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v")), paste0("co", "do"))))

example2 <- example
example2[[ paste0("co","de") ]] <- with(example2, ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v"))

library(dplyr)
mutate(example, !!paste0("co", "de") := ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v"))

library(data.table)
exampleDT <- as.data.table(example)
exampleDT[, paste("co", "de") := ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v")]

library(collapse)
ftransform(example, 
  setNames(list(ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v")), paste0("co", "do")))

'transform(example, %s = ifelse(u == 1, "u", "v"))' |>
   sprintf(paste0("co", "de")) |>
   parse(text = _) |>
   eval()
```